# How to put my QMainWindow behind my OpenGL application?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opengl, process

I created a QMainWindow (inherits) which opens as I expect.

I would like to start a process (An OpenGL application/game), when you click on a button inside the QMainWindow.

The problem is that my game opens behind my QMainWindow and I don't know how to put in foreground my QMainWindow.

This is my code :

```
bool MainWindow::ExecuteProcess(const QString & program, const QStringList & arguments, qint64 *pid)
{
    return QProcess::startDetached(program, arguments, QApplication::applicationDirPath(), pid);
}
```

Comment: Do You have a means of obtaining the window id associated with the OpenGL application?

Comment: Or changing the gfx bg/fg priority of my QMainWindow or the OpenGL application ?

Comment: Show us your code which starts your game.

Comment: @EduardWirch I added the code. I have this problem only on OSX (not on Windows). The game is an Irrlicht/OpenGL application